# Why does 'find -mtime +1' include today's files when used in a script?

Tags: shell, find

I'm using the following `find` command in a script:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1
```

When I use it from an interactive shell, this gives only old files, but in the script it also gives today's files.  Why?   What can I do to get the same behaviour as the interactive invocation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) an example directory with files that should and files that should not be found; ii) the exact script you are using.

Comment: Also, how are you executing your script?  Might it have a different idea of time zone (and hence of the start of day) than your interactive shell?

Comment: it shouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

You should include `-daystart` in your commandline:

```
-daystart
      Measure  times  (for  -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime)
      from the beginning of today rather  than  from  24  hours  ago.   This
      option only affects tests which appear later on the command line.
```

**Without that**, if you run your script from a cronjob after midnight you get different results from running it later during the day by hand.